# Request for help with two integrals

Tags: cv.complex-variables, integration, differential-calculus

It would be great if someone can help me do these integrals - using numerical integration on Mathematica it seems that these converge - in what follows $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $q \in \mathbb{N}$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$

- $\int _0 ^\infty dx\text{ } tanh (\pi \sqrt{x} )[ \frac{1}{x + a^2 + (\frac{n}{q})^2 }  - \frac{1}{x + a^2 + n^2 } ]  $
- $\int_0 ^\infty dx \text{ }\frac{tanh(\pi \sqrt{x})}{\sqrt{x + a^2 } } [ coth (\pi q \sqrt{x + a^2 } ) - coth (\pi \sqrt{x + a^2 } )   ] $

I am wondering if there is some complex analysis trick that can help here...

Comment: Have you tried to use $$\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\frac{y^2}{y^2+(k+\frac12)^2}=\pi y\tanh(\pi y)$$?

Comment: For $a=n=1$ and $q=2$, the value of the first integral is $0.27092733012243642067462062834169051560736001350324$, which is not recognized by Maple's identify() command or by the inverse symbolic calculator site (http://oldweb.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).  That makes me dubious that there is any useful closed form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my attempt at the first one:
\begin{multline*}
\int\limits_0^\infty\tanh(\pi\sqrt x)\left(\frac1{x+c^2}-\frac1{x+d^2}\right)dx\\=2\int\limits_0^\infty y\tanh(\pi y)\left(\frac1{y^2+c^2}-\frac1{y^2+d^2}\right)dy\\=\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^\infty\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\frac{y^2}{y^2+(k+\frac12)^2}\left(\frac1{y^2+c^2}-\frac1{y^2+d^2}\right)dy\\=\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^\infty\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\frac{(d^2-c^2)y^2}{(y^2+(k+\frac12)^2)(y^2+c^2)(y^2+d^2)}dy\\=\frac{2(d^2-c^2)}\pi\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{y^2}{(y^2+(k+\frac12)^2)(y^2+c^2)(y^2+d^2)}dy\\=(|d|-|c|)\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\frac1{(|k+\frac12|+|c|)(|k+\frac12|+|d|)}\\=\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}\left(\frac1{|k+\frac12|+|c|}-\frac1{|k+\frac12|+|d|}\right)\\=2(\psi(|d|+\frac12)-\psi(|c|+\frac12))
\end{multline*}
I believe the second integral can be treated similarly by expanding $\coth$ into elementary fractions too.

Just don't ask me whether all this was legitimate :)

Comment: (1) Thanks! This is out-of-the-blue! :) Can you kindly explain/define the $\psi$ function that you used and the integration that you did in the step just before introducing it?

Comment: (2) Also I believe that the summation identity you have used is kind of the derivative of two other identities that I have been using to get these integrals in the first place! - $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} log (\frac{n^2}{q^2} + a^2 ) = 2log [ 2 sinh (\pi q \vert a\vert ) ] $ and $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}+ \frac{1}{2}} log (\frac{n^2}{q^2} + a^2 ) = 2log [ 2 cosh (\pi q \vert a\vert ) ] $ - but these identities are zeta-function regularized identities - so I would be surprised if mathematicians also use them as legitimate ones!

Comment: So you are suggesting that I revert these coth functions back to these summations to do these integrals?

Comment: $\psi$ is the logarithmic derivative of the $\Gamma$; in Mathematica, $\psi(z)$ is PolyGamma[z] - you can see it e.~g. at the [Wolfram functions site](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/02), where it is defined through$$\psi(z)=-\gamma+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\frac1k-\frac1{k+z-1}\right).$$

Comment: As for the integration, I've just decomposed $\frac{y^2}{(y^2+b^2)(y^2+c^2)(y^2+d^2)}$ into elementary fractions and then integrated separately each summand using
$$
\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{dy}{y^2+e^2}=\frac\pi{2|e|}.
$$

Comment: And for $\coth$ I would guess expressing
$$
\pi y\coth(\pi y)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{y^2}{y^2+n^2}
$$
would do it.

Comment: But there isn't any modulus in the way you have used them...

Comment: Modulus is just to indicate that one has to take the positive square root

Comment: Is this the same answer as one gets by giving the following to Mathematica - Assuming [  c \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Reals  , 
 Sum [  1/ ( Abs[c] + Abs[k + 1/2])  - 
   1/ ( Abs[d] + Abs[k + 1/2])  , {k , 1, Infinity}]]

Comment: Mathematica thinks the answer is "-PolyGamma [3/2 + mod(c) ] + PolyGamma [  3/2 + mod(d)]" - is this the same as yours?

Comment: Not exactly - the summation over all integers must be split into $-k-1/2$ for negative $k$ and $k+1/2$ for nonnegative $k$.

Comment: Right - got it - then Mathematica and yours match!

Comment: In detail: $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f(|k+\frac12|)=\sum_{k<0}f(-k-\frac12)+\sum_{k\geqslant0}f(k+\frac12)$ $=\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k-\frac12)+\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(k+\frac12)=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k-\frac12)$

Comment: No - I meant they match when I correctly give Mathematica this input - 
Assuming [  c \[Element] Reals && d \[Element] Reals  , 
 Sum [  1/ ( Abs[c] + Abs[k + 1/2])  - 
   1/ ( Abs[d] + Abs[k + 1/2])  , {k , -Infinity, Infinity}]]

Comment: OK I see. It probably does what I said in my previous comment...

Comment: I am now wondering if this trick of yours will go through if I change the integrals to $\int_0 ^\infty tanh(\pi \sqrt{x}) [\frac{a}{x + c^2} - \frac{b}{x + d^2}  ] dx  $

Comment: Also can you explain how you thought of this trick!? :)  You just knew it? Or could you just see the Polygamma function?

Comment: In this version you will get (if I am not mistaken) integral of $\frac{\sqrt x}{x+*^2}$ and this does not converge...

Comment: No I did not see $\psi$ and in fact my first try was wrong (I obtained $\cot$ in place of $\psi$). I just thought that the fractions you have would match well with the fractions from the expansion of $\tanh$ that I mentioned in my very first comment :)

Comment: Seems like I left one of your questions unanswered. The involved expansions of $\tanh$, $\coth$ and $\psi$ are OK mathematically - they converge slowly but they do converge. Two things I did not even try to check are (1) whether it is OK to interchange summation and integration in this case and (2) whether it is OK to regroup terms in the sum of two expansions for $\psi$ in the end.

Comment: @user6818 You've been right in your penultimate comment - what actually converges is $\int\limits_0^\infty\frac{\sqrt x dx}{(x+p^2)(x+c^2)}=\frac\pi{|p|+|c|}$, and the calculation becomes much shorter this way